# AttributeError: 'SerialBus' object has no attribute 'can'

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python code to receive the can data via a `USB2CAN` device. I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: 'SerialBus' object has no attribute 'can'

```
from can.interfaces import serial

import random
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ser= can.interfaces.serial.serial_can.SerialBus('COM5',115200,timeout=None,rtscts=0)

for i in range(100) :
    s= ser.can.interfaces.serial.SerialBus._recv_internal(timeout=None)
    print(s)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `s = can.interfaces` not `s = ser.can.interfaces`?

Comment: i changed it to can.interfaces. But it isn't working still

Comment: Now i am getting the below error                                                                                                                                          console output                                                                                                                   
(None, False)
(None, False)
(None, False)